# Detect WDF driver upgrade

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a driver and installing using WiX installer, using TAG "**`difx:Driver`**". My driver is unload disabled (to avoid unauthorized unload).

Can I detect driver being upgraded / or my MSI being upgraded / uninstalled, so that I can preemptively unload driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditions can be hard. I am short on time, just some hints I am afraid. I think this got very messy, but I will look back when I get a minute.

***Major Upgrade***: During a major upgrade WiX-built MSI files set the following property: **`WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED`** (or **`WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED`** is also possible if you allow downgrades). This is for the new setup being installed, version 2 if you like. The version 1 setup that is being uninstalled has another property set, the MSI-standard **`UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE`**. This can be very confusing.

So the conclusion is that the condition **`WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED`** is true in a major upgrade scenario **in the newer setup that is running**. Bullet points:

- **Setup 2**: **`WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED`** is true.
- **Setup 1**: **`UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE`** is true - whilst it is being uninstalled.

***Uninstall***: The conditon **`REMOVE="ALL"`** is true only during uninstall.

***Installed***: The condition **`Installed`** will be true for all installation modes except fresh install, and (astonishingly for many) for Setup 2 (the new version) during a major upgrade. A major upgrade is a new product, so the condition Installed is not true. The new product is not installed yet. Installed will be true for a minor upgrade.

Comment: Thanks,  how wix replaces .sys files of unload disabled driver. On pre Windows 10 its possible to replace BOOT START drivers, but after Windows 10, its not possible.(tried mannually we can rename)

Comment: I am not a driver guy, but just to be sure, you have updated all version numbers? The driver files are signed?

Comment: Thanks, driver files are WHQL signed.